# Como instalar o express no ubuntu através do npm?

Tags: npm, express.js

Quando tento instalar o *Express* no *Ubuntu*, com o comando `npm install express`, ocorre este erro:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/flavio/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/flavio/node_modules/nodejsSchoolOfNet/package.json'
npm WARN flavio No description
npm WARN flavio No repository field.
npm WARN flavio No README data
npm WARN flavio No license field.
```

Comment: Tente primeiro `npm init`, para criar o .json que identifica os pacotes a serem instalados. Depois `npm install express --save`

Comment: Você quer instalar apenas dentro de um projeto ou global?

Comment: Quero instalar global

Answer (score 2):

Parece que você está tentando instalar o pacote dentro de um projeto Node e não de forma global no SO. Para fazer isso você pode usar o seguinte comando:

`npm install -g express@latest`

Se existir um `package.json` no diretório local, aonde você está tetando rodar o comando, pode simplesmente utilizar:

`npm install express`

ou

`npm install express --save-dev` caso seja uma dependência somente para desenvolvimento, o que no caso do Express eu creio que não seja.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro crie um novo projeto utilizando o comando "npm init". Isso criará um arquivo chamado "package.json" na sua pasta. Depois utilize o comando "npm install express --save" ("**--save**" caso queira salvar o express como uma dependência do seu projeto).